# How to increase customer login page captcha size(width,height) programmatically?

Tags: magento2, captcha

> I am trying to  increase customer login page capcha size(width,height)
>   programmatically magento 2?

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: we have custom theme

Comment: what exactly magento version using ?

Comment: i am using magento 2.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

For that you need to override below file to your theme or custom module.

> /var/www/html/folder-Name/vendor/magento/module-captcha/view/frontend/templates/default.phtml

You can find code like this.

```
<div class="control captcha-image">
    <img alt="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Please type the letters and numbers below')) ?>" class="captcha-img" height="<?= /* @noEscape */ (float) $block->getImgHeight() ?>" src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($captcha->getImgSrc()) ?>"z/>
    <button type="button" class="action reload captcha-reload" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Reload captcha')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reload captcha')) ?></span></button>
</div>
```

In `<img>` field You can add custom width & height to inline.

I hope it works!.

Comment: its worked but capcha image size increasing with blurs ie the problem is there any way to increase original image size

Comment: @hiteshbalpande let me check if found solution for that.

Comment: ok chirag i am also trying

Answer (score 0):

Hi solution is here with proper resolution.

Override below file to your theme.

> /var/www/html/folder-Name/vendor/magento/module-captcha/view/frontend/templates/default.phtml

Add below css to your default.phtml at the bottom.

```
<style type="text/css">
.control.captcha-image .captcha-img {transform:scale(1.2);-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;}
button.action.reload{margin-left: 50px;}
</style>
```

Comment: even it is giving blur only

Comment: Check this: https://prnt.sc/l7jh5e

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend disabling default captcha and implementing Google reCaptcha as it's very simple to implement, reliable and simple to use.